# Getting grandfather class of an element - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a Python script that grabs job titles. An example of a job title in a list class looks like this:

[Job Title ex.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PngXi.png)

To grab any keywords such as Summer or in this case I grabbed this title individually, I used xpath which looks like this:

```
    temp = web.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Summer 2016 Co-op - Software Test Engineer Intern')]")
```

I want to grab the text that shows where it is without trying to grab that specifically as each job will change in my program. Basically I want to grab the grandfather class and select the div class that contains the location of the job (or just grab other elements in the same parent class), however, using xpath with '..' and

```
web.get_attributes('outerHTML')
```

only returns the current class instead of the whole list div class.

The code for this div class looks like this:

```
<li class="row list-item list_rows" id="row_3b11ddb0571c6c4908b2cca98804ec00">

        <div class="list-item-logo">
                                <a href="https://rit-csm.symplicity.com/students/index.php?s=employers&amp;mode=profile&amp;id=c2c0dd779fe969740566778ee0816177&amp;ss=jobmatches"><img src="./job postings _ RIT Job Zone_files/view.php" alt="Logo" class="avatar avatar-square"></a>
                        </div>

        <div class="list-item-body">

            <div class="list-item-title">
                **<a href="https://rit-csm.symplicity.com/students/index.php?mode=form&amp;id=3b11ddb0571c6c4908b2cca98804ec00&amp;s=jobs&amp;ss=jobmatches" class="ListPrimaryLink">Summer 2016 Co-op - Software Test Engineer Intern</a>**                                 

            </div>

            <div class="list-data-columns">                                                         
                Co-op
            </div>
            <div class="list-data-columns">
                <a href="https://rit-csm.symplicity.com/students/index.php?s=employers&amp;ss=list&amp;mode=profile&amp;id=c2c0dd779fe969740566778ee0816177" class="ListPrimaryLink">Veson Nautical</a> - Boston, Massachusetts<br>Lebanon, New Hampshire               
                 </div>                                                                                                                                                                             
              </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

The line that didn't get bolded apparently is the one which got selected by using the xpath line of code.

```
**<a href="https://rit-csm.symplicity.com/students/index.php?mode=form&amp;id=3b11ddb0571c6c4908b2cca98804ec00&amp;s=jobs&amp;ss=jobmatches" class="ListPrimaryLink">Summer 2016 Co-op - Software Test Engineer Intern</a>**
```

How do I get to the highest parent class (the list) or even getting the other div classes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an xpath which selects only the `a` tag, you can use an xpath that takes some ancestor of the element (for example `li`).

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Summer 2016 Co-op - Software Test Engineer Intern')]/ancestor::li[contains(@id, 'row_')]
```